# What is wrong with my handle_clients function

Tags: c, sockets, networking, telnet

Fairly new to socket programming, so here goes my question. What is wrong? What my function does, is take input from the telnet session and then when you press 'enter' it should go break the while loop. But it doesn't for some reason. I can't figure out why either, I've tried various ways but, nothing I've tried thus far worked yet.

```
void handle_clients(socket,address)
    int *socket;
    const char *address;
{
    char msg[256];
    char cmd[128];
    int bytes;

    memset(msg,0,sizeof(msg));
    memset(cmd,0,sizeof(cmd));
    while(1) {
        send(*socket,"CMD >> ",7,0);
        bytes = 0;
        while((bytes = recv(*socket,cmd,sizeof(cmd),0)) > 0) {
            if(bytes < 0) {
                sprintf(msg,"Error: receiving from %s.\r\n",
                    address);
                send(*socket,msg,strlen(msg),0);
                break;
            }
            if(cmd[bytes] == 10 || cmd[bytes] == 13) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if(strcmp(cmd,"exit") == 0) {
            break;
        } else if(strcmp(cmd,"help") == 0) {
            sprintf(msg,"Commands: [exit,cmd,help]\r\n");
            send(*socket,msg,strlen(msg),0);
        } else if(strcmp(cmd,"cmd") == 0) {
            memset(cmd,0,sizeof(cmd));
            send(*socket,"Enter command: ",15,0);
            bytes = 0;
            while((bytes = recv(*socket,cmd,sizeof(cmd),0)) > 0) {
                if(bytes < 0) {
                    sprintf(msg,"Error: receiving from %s.\r\n",
                        address);
                    send(*socket,msg,strlen(msg),0);
                    break;
                }
                if(cmd[bytes] == 10 || cmd[bytes] == 13) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            system(cmd);
        } else {
            sprintf(msg,"Unknown command.\r\n");
            send(*socket,msg,strlen(msg),0);
        }
        memset(msg,0,sizeof(msg));
        memset(cmd,0,sizeof(cmd));
    }
}
```

Comment: There's lots more you can do to debug this. Have you used the debugger to verify exactly what is being received?

Comment: How do you know the `while` loop doesn't exit? all you `strcmp` calls ignore the `\r\n` at the end of the line (did you consider `memcmp` instead?, i.e. `memcmp(cmd,"exit",4)` or `strcmp(cmd,"exit\r\n")`) ... and that's just one of the concerns I can think of... Good luck, anyway!

Comment: `cmd[bytes]` is the byte *after* the last byte read. The last byte read will be `cmd[bytes - 1]` (unless `bytes` is 0)

Comment: You are ignoring the case when `recv()` returns zero, which means the peer has disconnected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it should go break the while loop. But it doesn't for some reason.

In addition to the issues pointed out by my peers, I think the answer to your specific inquiry lies in the nested `while` loops and the missing `\r\n` chars from the `strcmp`.

Since the `while` loops are nested, than `break` might break the nested loop while the container loop remains - so you're back in the next nested loop in your next iteration.

For example:

```
while(1) {
    send(*socket,"CMD >> ",7,0);
    bytes = 0;
    while((bytes = recv(*socket,cmd,sizeof(cmd),0))) {
        if(bytes < 0) {
            sprintf(msg,"Error: receiving from %s.\r\n",
                address);
            send(*socket,msg,strlen(msg),0);
            break; /* <= WHICH LOOP ARE WE BREAKING? */
        }
        if(cmd[bytes] == 10 || cmd[bytes] == 13) {
            break; /* <= WHICH LOOP ARE WE BREAKING? */
        }
    }
    // ...
 }
```

This is one of those cases where `goto` might be your friend...

...although I do think there are better and more elegant solutions and changes that might be required to your code before you go there.

Also, What's the point of re-reading the data, if you're overwriting the existing buffer?

I find it almost (in this case) more convenient and likely to ignore the possible case of incomplete TCP/IP packets/commands.

In this specific case, it seems okay to assume that if the command doesn't end with a new line, something is wrong and we can disconnect. Such short commands should pass in a single TCP/IP packet. i.e.:

```
while(1) {
    send(*socket,"CMD >> ",7,0);
    bytes = 0;
    bytes = recv(*socket,cmd,sizeof(cmd),0);
    if(!bytes) { // closed by peer
       close(*socket);
       return;
    }
    if(bytes < 0 || cmd[bytes-1] == 10 || cmd[bytes-1] == 13) {
       if(errno == EINTR)
         continue;
       sprintf(msg,"Error: receiving from %s.\r\n",
                   address);
       close(*socket);
       return;
    }
    if(strcmp(cmd,"exit\r\n") == 0) {
        break;
    } else if(strcmp(cmd,"help\r\n") == 0) {}
    // ...
 }
```

This code obviously ignores the possibility of multiple commands being read in a single `recv` (i.e., the buffer being `"help\r\ncmd\r\nX\r\nexit\r\n"`)... but you'll solve that at some point.

Answer (score 0):

This has a logic problem:

```
 while((bytes = recv(*socket,cmd,sizeof(cmd),0)) > 0) {
        if(bytes < 0) {

        }
 }
```

bytes will be always greater than zero so the if(bytes<0){} block will never
execute.

You may want to change it to

```
 while((bytes = recv(*socket,cmd,sizeof(cmd),0))) {
        if(bytes < 0) {

        }
 }
```

If bytes equals to zero, it will not enter while loop.

Comment: @Myst - The while(bytes){}  is true if `bytes` is not equal to zero which means It could be a negative value and it will execute the inner code of  the while loop.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, after posting my comment I realized my mistake... I didn't notice the OP had the ` > 0` in their code. That's why I deleted my comment.